# Generate a wallet file from a spend key in the command line using the CLI wallet in a "non-interactive" way for scripting purpose

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, wallet, spend-key, cli

I have a monero spend key and I want to generate a new wallet file using the CLI, but I want to do it in an non-interactive way so I can use this same command in my scripts. I tried doing:

> monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-spend-key "xxxxxx"

But it hits me with an input for the spend key. How can I pass in the spend key from the command line and also not have a password to the wallet file. Or possibly how do I set the wallet password via the command line if I wanted to.

Comment: "But it hits me with an input for the spend key." <- I presume you mean it asks you for *other* inputs such as wallet file, password, view key (which you can also provide as additional command line parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `--generate-from-json` for this.
The input fields in the JSON file are:

```
      version: integer, should be 1
      filename: string, path/filename for the newly created wallet
      scan_from_height: 64 bit unsigned integer, optional
      password: string, optional
      viewkey: string, hex representation
      spendkey: string, hex representation
      seed: string, optional, list of words separated by spaces
```